# Group list of tuples by first element, get average of second element

Tags: scala

I have a list of tuples, like so:

```
val list = List((1, 20), (2, 20), (1, 30), (2, 40), (2, 60))
```

And I want to map it to a list of tuples where:

> The first element is unique.
>   The second element is averaged from tuples with identical first value.

i.e. for the list above, a mapping to: `List((1, 25), (2, 40))`

I suppose I could do this like so:

```
list.groupBy(_._1)
  .map { case (key, value) =>
    (key, value.map(_._2).sum / value.length)}.toList
```

But converting to and from a map like this seems needlessly verbose and expensive. Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Not really, think about the algorithm in your head, the first step is to group things, that requires an intermediate data structure. However, you can do little optimizations if you write a tail-recursive function yourself, for example tracking the sum and the count at the same time you do the grouping.

Comment: You can simplify the "big map" with a mapValues :
`list.groupBy( _._1 ).mapValues { value => value.map(_._2).sum / value.length }.toList`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could potentially use `Scala 2.13`'s [`groupMap`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.x/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#groupMap[K,B](key:A=%3EK)(f:A=%3EB):scala.collection.immutable.Map[K,CC[B]]) to make it slightly less verbose:

```
// val tuples = List((1, 20), (2, 20), (1, 30), (2, 40), (2, 60))
tuples.groupMap(_._1)(_._2).mapValues(vs => vs.sum / vs.size).toList
// List((1, 25), (2, 40))
```

Note the intermediate result of `groupMap`:

```
tuples.groupMap(_._1)(_._2)
// Map(1 -> List(20, 30), 2 -> List(20, 40, 60))
```

Comment: Why not `groupMapReduce(_._1) { case (_, v) => (v, 1) } (combineTuples)`? To compute the sum and the count at once, as a tuple. And then `view.mapValues { case (sum, count) => sum / count }.toList`.

Comment: Indeed, you can prepare a reduce step in the map step and produce a sum and a count per key as output of a `groupMapReduce`. If the nbr of values per key becomes important, then a `groupMapReduce` solution would be more performant. Otherwise, I'd use the `groupMap` for simplicity. This could look like: `tuples.groupMapReduce(_._1) { case (_, v) => (v, 1) }{ case (a, b) => (a._1 + b._1, a._2 + 1) }.mapValues { case (sum, count) => sum/count }.toList` At that point an imperative solution would actually probably look better.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done using `groupBy` and `groupMap`

```
list.groupBy(_._1).view.mapValues(value => value.map(_._2).sum / value.length).toList
```

**Output:** `List((1,25), (2,40))`

```
list.groupMap(_._1)(_._2).view.mapValues(value => value.sum / value.size).toList
```

**Output:** `List((1,25), (2,40))`

```
 list.groupMap(_._1)(_._2)
```

**Output:** `Map(1 -> List(20, 30), 2 -> List(20, 40, 60))`

```
 list.groupBy(_._1)
```

**Output:** `HashMap(1 -> List((1,20), (1,30)), 2 -> List((2,20), (2,40), (2,60)))`

```
  list.groupBy(_._2)
```

**Output:** `HashMap(20 -> List((1,20), (2,20)), 60 -> List((2,60)), 40 -> List((2,40)), 30 -> List((1,30)))`